# What does the Type parameter for Thread and Runnable signify?

Tags: java

Look at the following code from the `ThreadFactory` interface

```
 public Thread<T> newThread(Runnable<T> runnable);
```

What does s the type parameter convey here ? I mean Collection makes sense since T is specifying the type of objects that can go into the Collection but what does  Runnable or Thread mean ?

Comment: Where did you see that code? It says [`Thread newThread(Runnable r)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html#newThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik first answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762991/how-does-java-util-concurrent-executor-work/5766067

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, bring it on! the owl is up all night ;)

Comment: @Subhra If you actually look up the ThreadFactory code from Oracle, not once does it mention templatisation.

Comment: Subhra, that guy was obviously typing from memory. As you say it's meaningless and indeed it is not real.

Comment: @nathanwhite please see the source of that code in the link I gave in another comment above

Comment: @Subhra I did, but then the first person to get it wrong simply influenced a second person to get it wrong. If it's not on Oracles website as that, it isn't the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [ThreadFactory.newThread(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html#newThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) there is no generic type, nor is Runnable or Thread a generic interface/class. The original must have been in error.

Answer (score 0):

Thread class you are creating,it has to be the subclass of some other class, it can’t extend from the Thread class. This is because Java does not allow a class to inherit from more than one class. That's why Runnable interface to implement threads.

For better understanding,just take a look of these two links [this1](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4202) and [this2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853167/runnable-with-a-parameter)

Comment: Its not clear how this related to the OP's question about generics?

Comment: I'm talking about thread implementation with runnable interface.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like [Runnable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Runnable.java#Runnable) this was intended with the Runnable interface. Maybe you are getting confused with [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). Here the generic type will be the type returned.

Comment: I am not confused with Callable . Please see the [source of this code here in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762991/how-does-java-util-concurrent-executor-work/5766067) .

Comment: That was probably just a mistake.